# Ionic/Angular how to remove borders from inputs

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, sass

I get the below black borders in my input fields. How do I remove the ugly 1px border around the controls?

I can't find it in the CSS or don't know how to look for it as I'm new to it.

Code:

```
<ion-col col-8>
    <input formControlName="cardno" placeholder="{{ 'PAYMENT_CARD_NUMBER' | translate }}" card-number />
</ion-col>
```

Result ugly 1px borders around inputs:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clean Inputs & textarea:

```
textarea, input 
{ 
 background:none; 
 outline: none; 
 -webkit-appearance: none; 
 box-shadow: none !important; 
 border: none; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple Way

```
input{
   border: none; // for black border
   outline: none; // for focus outline remove
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove borders from `<input>`, just set `border` property to `none`.

```css
input {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Card number">
```

For more info, refer [MDN documentation on border](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) property.

If you want to keep the bottom border, and add some padding and margin, see below example.

```css
input {
  height: 2rem;
  margin: 0rem 1rem;
  padding: 0rem 1rem;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e4e9f0;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Card number">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a style attribute to your input and set the border to none

```html
<ion-col col-8>
    <input style="border:none;" formControlName="cardno" placeholder="{{ 'PAYMENT_CARD_NUMBER' | translate }}" card-number />
</ion-col>
```

If you have more than one input tag in your html-file I would prefer to use an external CSS-file and write the following lines to disable the borders for all inputs!

```css
input {
  border: none;
}
```